# Minor bug in edit summary (?)

Tags: bug

I recently made an edit to someone else's question (formatting) but forgot to type something in the Edit Summary box before submitting the changes.

So I went back to the editing-mode and entered a reason for the changes. I know that any edits done within 5 minutes from one another get merged into "one edit", which is great in this context where I simply forgot to write an edit summary.

However, I discovered that the edit summary is basically ignored if no changes are made to the question itself. I went back and tested by adding a full-stop where it was missing and re-entered the edit summary from before, which worked.

Looks like there is some check if something has been altered in the question when saving an edit, and if not nothing happens.

This obviously makes sense, but perhaps the logic should also check if the edit summary was changed?

A minor bug (or so it seems), but I thought I'd share it anyway since I couldn't find any earlier bug reports on it.

Comment: Apparently people have been asking for this for over 6 years.

Comment: @Stijn, oh, didn't know that's called a grace period. I've seen the term before but thought it was related to edits pending approval. Cheers! Marked this as dupe.